# local bootstrap with laravel 4.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I have a default blade file that yields other contents this is where im calling the link to style sheet and javascript i downloaded bootstrap 3.3.5 and created a link to it here is my default blade

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap335/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/plug- ins/1.10.7/integration/bootstrap/3/dataTables.boâ€Œâ€‹otstrap.css" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"> </script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.7/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">

@yield('content')


</div>
</body>
</html>
```

The bootstrap is working properly in my views except one. i don't know the problem because it works fine on the others and it is extends the default blade file

Comment: Are you getting any errors at all? What does the code look like for the page you get errors on?

Comment: Use `asset` function. `<link ... href="{{ asset('bootstrap335/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}">`

Comment: @James hmm i did not have any errors. the styles just does not apply

Comment: @Hkan that did the trick! thanks!! :)

Comment: @BourneShady I believe the problem was the fact that you were missing the `/` in the link to Bootstrap. So, if you were at `http://example.com/blah`, it would be looking for it at `http://example.com/blah/boostrap335/css/bootstrap.min.css`. With `/boostrap335/css/bootstrap.min.css`, it would correctly load `http://example.com/boostrap335/css/bootstrap.min.css`